# PHP add new data to multidimensional array

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I'm a newbie to multidimensional array's

I have a form that stores data into an array.
I would like my users to re-use the form and store data to the array. 
So my idea was a multidimensional array that stores a new array everytime the form is used.

But my problem is that I have no idea how to do this.

Here is my form:

```
            $customer = '';
            $customer .= '<tr><td>customername:<br/><input type="text" name="customer[customername]" value="" /> </td></tr>';
            $customer .= '<tr><td>customertitle 1:<br/><input type="text" name="customer[customertitle1]" value="" /> </td></tr>';
            $customer .= '<tr><td>customeremail 1:<br/><input type="text" name="customer[customeremail1]" value="" /> </td></tr>';
            $customer .= '<tr><td>customertitle 2:<br/><input type="text" name="customer[customertitle2]" value="" /> </td></tr>';
            $customer .= '<tr><td>customeremail 2:<br/><input type="text" name="customer[customeremail2]" value="" /> </td></tr>';
            echo $customer;
```

This saves the form in an array:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
```

And this shows the first value of the array:

```
        $customers = array(get_option('customer'));
        foreach($customers as $customer){
          echo $customer["customername"];
        }
```

I hope this makes sence to anyone!!!!

Comment: Are you calling Wordpress' `get_option`?

Comment: "Stor[ing] a new array every time the form is used" implies you are building up a collection of data from multiple form submissions. If so, you probably want some sort of persistent data storage (like a database). PHP process state does not persist across page loads so multidimensional arrays would not help.

Comment: @watcher Yes this is a wordpress call.

Comment: @Andrew. There is a database where all this is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes figured it out

Here goes for the ones that wish to know:
First create a function to get the current array.
Save the new value from the form with update_option

```
function savearray (){
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
// get the option
$customers = get_option( 'customers' );
// add new data to the option
$customers[] = $_POST['customers'];
// save it back to the db
update_option( 'customers', $customers );
}
```

Then create a form that places data in arrays by name

```
<?php 
$customers = '';
$customers .= '<tr><td>Name:<br/><input type="text" name="customers[name]" value="" /> </td></tr>';
$customers .= '<tr><td>Contact 1:<br/><input type="text" name="customers[contact1]" value="" /> </td></tr>';
echo $customers;
?>
```

So this works....
Now the next step.

I want to only show the name of the costumer and create a link to the data of the specific costumer.
So I did this:

```
 <?php      
$customers = get_option('customers');
foreach($customers as $val){
  echo '<a href="#">'.$val["name"] . '</a><br>';
}           
?>
```

This tells me that I want to view the name of all costumers in tha array and create a link.
I have no idea how to target the specific data in the array.

Anyone?????

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

Ex:

```
<?php
 // add a new consumer in your new array  
   $consumer["name"] = "John Doe";
   $consumer["email"] = "toto@yopmail.com";
   ...
   $a = new ArrayObject();
   $a->append($consumer)


   // for get a consumer in the array
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
          // Some instruction
    }
?>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: It is not clear how this relates to the question. Putting a single hash into an array doesn't really accomplish anything.